# Simplest way to allow range queries on Numeric fields in Lucene 4

Tags: java, lucene

I'm revisiting my code that was originally written for Lucene 3.0 (I then updated it so it worked for 4.0 but haven't yet taken advantage of all 4.0 improvements) .

For numeric fields that I want to be able to do range queries for I add field to the document as follows:

```
BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(value, 0, bytes);
doc.add(new Field(fieldname, bytes.utf8ToString(),
    new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_NOT_STORED)));
```

Then I have to have a custom query parser overriding methods  newTermQuery() and new RangeQuery()

i.e

```
public class ReleaseQueryParser extends MultiFieldQueryParser
{

    public ReleaseQueryParser(String[] strings, Analyzer a)
    {
        super(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_VERSION, strings, a);
    }

    protected Query newTermQuery(Term term)
    {
        if (
                (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS.getName())) ||
                        (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS_MEDIUM.getName())) ||
                        (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_MEDIUMS.getName()))
                )
        {
            try
            {

                int number = Integer.parseInt(term.text());
                BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
                NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(number, 0, bytes);
                TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(), bytes.utf8ToString()));
                return tq;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                //If not provided numeric argument just leave as is, won't give matches
                return super.newTermQuery(term);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return super.newTermQuery(term);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Query newRangeQuery(String field,
                               String part1,
                               String part2,
                               boolean startInclusive,
                               boolean endInclusive)
    {
        if (
                (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS.getName())) ||
                        (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS_MEDIUM.getName())) ||
                        (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_MEDIUMS.getName()))
                )
        {
            BytesRef bytes1 = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
            BytesRef bytes2 = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
            NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part1), 0, bytes1);
            NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part2), 0, bytes2);
            part1 = bytes1.utf8ToString();
            part2 = bytes2.utf8ToString();
        }
        TermRangeQuery query = (TermRangeQuery)
                super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
        return query;

    }
}
```

Ive always thought this code rather clunky and was wondering if it could be now be simplified somewhat ?

**Update**

Attempted to use IntField as follows

doc.add(new IntField(field.getName(), value, new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_NOT_STORED)));

Compiled okay, but my index build test method

```
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(ir);
Terms terms = fields.terms(field.getName());
TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
termsEnum.next();
assertEquals(value, NumericUtils.prefixCodedToInt(termsEnum.term()));
```

fails with NullPointerException on terms.iterator() line.

Changed to

```
doc.add(new IntField(field.getName(), value, new FieldType(IntField.TYPE_NOT_STORED)));
```

and that worked, but Im suprised that that the line

```
NumericUtils.prefixCodedToInt(termsEnum.term())
```

still works, I guess IntField is just a wrapper around the ByteRef code I originally had.

Then rewrote QueryParser as follows

```
public class ReleaseQueryParser extends MultiFieldQueryParser
{

    public ReleaseQueryParser(String[] strings, Analyzer a)
    {
        super(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_VERSION, strings, a);
    }

    protected Query newTermQuery(Term term)
    {
        if (
                (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS.getName())) ||
                        (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS_MEDIUM.getName())) ||
                        (term.field().equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_MEDIUMS.getName()))
                )
        {
            return NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(term.field(), Integer.parseInt(term.text()), Integer.parseInt(term.text()), true, true);
        }
        else
        {
            return super.newTermQuery(term);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Query newRangeQuery(String field,
                               String part1,
                               String part2,
                               boolean startInclusive,
                               boolean endInclusive)
    {
        if (
                (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS.getName())) ||
                        (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_TRACKS_MEDIUM.getName())) ||
                        (field.equals(ReleaseIndexField.NUM_MEDIUMS.getName()))
                )
        {
            return NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(field, Integer.parseInt(part1), Integer.parseInt(part2),startInclusive, endInclusive);
        }
        else
        {
            return super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
        }
    }
}
```

and that worked, I didn't really want to use a range query within newTermQuery(Term term) but I couldn't see an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IntField` or `LongField` classes provided by lucene . Then you can just query the index using a standard `NumericRangeQuery` of the specified type

Comment: thanks I have improved solution based on your info, although maybe room for further improvement.